# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Authorization failed: ClientId *** was not found on the server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using HTTP Adapters to make API request to the server. When i run the app from browser, the requests work fine. While working from iOS Simulators it works for iOS 6S Plus 9.3, but if try with any other simulator it says,

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId
>   b***************************d was not found on the server. [project
>   MyProject]

On simulator i get the following screen whenever i hit a service.

[image: This popup comes first]

[image: On click the "details" i get this information]

I checked the MobileFirst Operations Console and it has one device in its Device list.
[image: MFP Operations Console Device section]

How can i solve this issue so that it will work for any device with any OS on it?

Comment: @sansid1093, Can you try to reset the iOS simulator?

Comment: @IdanAdar : I did the reset for each iOS simulator and after it started making the api request. But after reset, when i ran the app for the first time i am getting this in the console `*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <Illigal API call> IBM MobileFirst Platform framework is not initialized. [WL mainHtmlFilePath] API should be used after the successful callback of the [WL initWithDelegate:] API. This is to ensure that IBM MobileFirst Platform framework initialization is complete and web resources are ready to be used.` and the app stops.

Comment: Okay. Did you in any way change the code in those areas?

Comment: @IdanAdar : No changes have been made. Both 'wlInit.js' and 'initOptions.js' are unchanged. In my index.html the order which i am calling the js is like this '<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script><script src="js/wlInit.js"></script>'. Could this do anything?

Comment: Did you create this order?

Comment: @IdanAdar : I am using Ionic & Angular in this MobileFirst Project. One of the blog for getting this up and running suggested to have it this way.